# Saving Uint8Array to an gzip after conversion

Tags: javascript, gzip, file-conversion, uint8array

I have been looking for client side conversion to gzip of file (in browser) and found [pako.](https://github.com/nodeca/pako)

Thing is that i am my running example for this conversion by using Node.js functions which are server side (at least this is my understanding of Node.js from what i read).

I would like to replace both "fs"(for writing to file) and "buffer" (for saving to format which is writable to the new function responsible for writing to file) to some native javascript functions.

This is the code.

```
var pako = require('pako'), data = "sample text";
var fs = require('fs');

data = pako.gzip(data);
var buffer = new Buffer(data.length);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    buffer.writeUInt8(data[i], i);

}

var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('output.gz');

wstream.write(buffer);
wstream.end();
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How am i supposed to save Uint8Array to function responsible for writing to file?

Comment: + I would like to replace current function which i am using to write to file

Comment: I don't want to use Node.js functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't really say what your end goal is, but I'm guessing you want to generate a file that the user can download from the browser. Using the [Blob API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) that's simple. The below is based on (read: pretty much identical to) [an example in the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Example_for_creating_a_URL_to_a_typed_array_using_a_blob):

```js
const data = 'sample text';
const gzipped = pako.gzip(data); // => Uint8Array
const blob = new Blob([gzipped], {type: 'application/gzip'});
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

console.log('Generated Blob; object URL: %s', blobUrl);

// render link
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', blobUrl);
link.innerHTML = 'Download file';
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pako@1.0.4/dist/pako_deflate.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry for not giving full explanation of what i wanted to do. I am not sure of how it should look myself but the main point was not using server computing. Saving and using filesystem is temporary to check if it is working but i would like to post gziped file to server directory, database in form which be readable right after ungziping.

Comment: Okay. Which part of that are you having trouble with?

Comment: I just noticed a snippet, nice! Did you included all Javascript files or only needed ones? I have been thinking about including only required ones for this operation.

Comment: I need to do some research myself to understand what is needed now.

Comment: As you can see in the snippet, I've included only `pako_deflate.js`.

Comment: Thanks for answering to my question.